# Can Windows server administrator inherit SQL SA privileges

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2, administrator

Can users who are part of Windows Administrators group inherit SA priveleges on SQL Server that is installed on Windows box

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to grant SA privileges to all local administrators, just create a sql login for the local administrator group and add it to the sysadmin server role.

If you do not want SA access, make sure that login is not part of the sysadmin server role.

However, a local administrator can impersonate other local windows accounts like the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account. That one always has SA access to any local SQL Server instance when using integrated security. That means you cannot really prevent a local admin from getting sysadmin access.

For details on gaining SA access to a SQL 2008R2 instance as a local admin, checkout this link: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! So, im my envrionment i have NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account with sa priveleges on sql server and there is a user XYZ who is administrator on the windows box but has only datareader rights on SQL server, so will this user XYZ be able to access SQL server with SA priveleges because of him being an administrator on the windows server? Pls let me know.. Thanks in advance

Comment: That is correct. In SQL Server 2008R2 `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` has sysadmin privileges on any local instance. Any local administrator can execute a program like sqlcmd "impersonating" that account and therefore gain sysadmin access themselves. - In SQL 2012 and 2014 the process is a little more complex, but it is still possible for a local admin to gain sysadmin on any local instance.

Comment: Please let me know the process for impersonation, if you can share the steps and can the user (described above) use SQL Mgmt Studio with sysadmin priveleges using impersonation?

Comment: I added a link above.